# XSLT: Sum of the values of a node where a preceding-sibling condition is met

Tags: xml, xslt

I am attempting to find the sum of the Amount tag where a preceding-sibling condition is met. The data comes from a Sql Data Base and the order of the XML cannot be changed.

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Table>
        <Store_NUM>
            1101
        </Store_NUM>
        <Amount>
            10,000
        </Amount>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <Store_NUM>
            1101
        </Store_NUM>
        <Amount>
            15,000
        </Amount>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <Store_NUM>
            1101
        </Store_NUM>
        <Amount>
            12,000
        </Amount>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <Store_NUM>
            1103
        </Store_NUM>
        <Amount>
            10,000
        </Amount>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <Store_NUM>
            1103
        </Store_NUM>
        <Amount>
            10,000
        </Amount>
    </Table>
    <Table1>
        <Run_Date>
            2013-12-06
        </Run_Date>
        <Run_Time>
            08:20:56.254
        </Run_Time>
    </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

I want to find the sum of  where Store_NUM equals 1101. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sum(//Table[normalize-space(Store_NUM) = '1101']/Amount)`. But your numbers using a comma are not in the right format, it should be floating point format.

If you have a variable or param `$foo` use `sum(//Table[normalize-space(Store_NUM) = $foo]/Amount)`.

Comment: Yes, the amounts are in the wrong format and that was a mistake on my part. I was using that as an example and I forgot that the data coming out is formatted as a float. I did have a small quibble with your code though, it seems as if it is looking at Amount as a child node rather than a sibling.

Comment: @AndrewLeon, the expression `Table[normalize-space(Store_NUM) = '1101']/Amount` in my suggestion selects `Amount` child elements of `Table` parent element that as well have a `Store_NUM` child with the value `1101`. So the `Amount` and `Store_NUM` are siblings of course, only the usual way is to put the predicate on the parent `Table` instead of writing `sum(//Table/Amount[normalize-space(preceding-sibling::Store_NUM) = '1101'])`.

Comment: I do apologize, it works great!! It is just that the string '1101' is actually a variable that comes into a template as a variable. I hard coded the store and it worked great, now I just need to find a way to get it to work with the param.

Comment: @AndrewLeon, added sample using parameter or variable reference.